# Storing non-literal enum values swift

Tags: swift, enums, uicolor

I am trying to create a list of custom colors that I can use throughout my app, and here is how I currently have it setup:

```
enum Colors {
   static let darkRed = UIColor(red: 181/255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor
   static let brown = UIColor(red: 134/255, green: 83/255, blue: 4/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
   static let tan = UIColor(red: 191/255, green: 136/255, blue: 39/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
}
```

I know Swift does not allow creation of enums with non-literal values, but I am looking for a better alternative to making each variable static.

Comment: Sorry, and why don't you like this solution? it looks good

Comment: What do you consider a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up `struct` and `enum`.

Your code between the braces belongs to `struct`, an `enum` has *cases*.

```
struct Colors {
   static let darkRed = UIColor(red: 181/255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor
   static let brown = UIColor(red: 134/255, green: 83/255, blue: 4/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
   static let tan = UIColor(red: 191/255, green: 136/255, blue: 39/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
}
```

Then you can call the members of the struct

```
let myColor = Colors.darkRred
```

However the naming convention is to use capitalized enum cases and static type properties.

Comment: An `enum` can also have static type properties, like `struct` and `class`.

Comment: Yes, but creating an `enum` without any cases is pretty silly.

Comment: You're right but in this case you have a true singleton without any initializers. Whereas a `struct` has to have a private initializer in this case which can be still accessed within its source file.

Comment: Stored type properties don't have an initializer by definition. From the documentation: *Unlike stored instance properties, you must always give stored type properties a default value. This is because the type itself does not have an initializer that can assign a value to a stored type property at initialization time*

Comment: I don't mean the stored type properties. I'm referring to the type which stores those properties. In this case `enum Colors` and `struct Colors`. The documentation only says that the (Meta-) TYPE (`Colors.self`) has no initializers but as I said the `struct` still can be initialized at least in its source file.

Answer (score 1):

I would have just created an extension to UIColor with computed static properties:

```
extension UIColor{
  static var darkRed: UIColor{
    return UIColor(red: 181/255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
  }
}
```

and the usage would be like that:

```
let darkRed = UIColor.darkRed.CGColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would pass the enum to a switch either in a class or just a function with your values defined.

```
enum ColorType {
    case FANCY_RED
    case BLUE
}

func makeColor(color: ColorType) -> CGColor{
    switch(color){
    case .BLUE:
        return UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 151/255, alpha: 1).CGColor;
    ...
    }
}
```

Another options would be to use a String and split and parse it but typo's would be more likely.

```
enum Color: String {
    case FANCY_RED = "1, 0, 0, 1"
}
```

Comment: Just a note: The Swift convention for naming enum cases is "upper camel case". e.g. FANCY_RED => FancyRed

Comment: Good to know. I should have another look at the conventions to catch the faux pas I've been making haha.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by vadian I would also use a `struct`. But if you want, for whatever reason, to use a `enum` you can create the same behavior:

```
enum Colors {
    case darkRed, brown, tan

    func color() -> CGColor{
        switch self{
        case .darkRed:
            return UIColor(red: 181/255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor
        case .brown:
            return UIColor(red: 134/255, green: 83/255, blue: 4/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        case .tan:
            return UIColor(red: 191/255, green: 136/255, blue: 39/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        }
    }
}
```

Then you get the values with:

```
let myColor = Colors.darkRed.color()
```